# Unable to interact with webrender page in touchdesigner, only move the render inside the container

Tags: user-interface

I was using some WebRender TOPs in touchdesigner and where previously I could interact with the page with the viewer active, now I can only move the rendered image about in the container.

Nothing seems to reset this behaviour that I've been able to find so far.

Thanks in advance!